# saving an entity by fetching data from other entity in spring mvc controller results in NullPointerException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I have 2 entity objects and i have linked one to jsp page using @ModelAttribute in spring mvc controller. When i try to save other entity from controller it results in nullpointerexception.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class Admin {

@Autowired
CompanyService companyService;
@Autowired
UserService userService;
User user = null;
@RequestMapping(value = "/companyregister", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupAddCompanyForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("newCompany") Company newCompany){

    return "registercompany";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/companyregister", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String AddCompany(Model model, @ModelAttribute("newCompany") Company newCompany, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "registercompany";
    }
    String id = newCompany.getCompanyId();
    user.setUserId(id);
    userService.saveUser(user);
    return "redirect:/";
}   

}
```

Console output

```
    Hibernate: drop table if exists Company cascade
    Hibernate: drop table if exists Student cascade
    Hibernate: drop table if exists User cascade
    Hibernate: create table Company (companyId varchar(255) not null, companyName varchar(255), description varchar(255), emailId varchar(255), hrName varchar(255), password varchar(255) not null, phone1 varchar(255), phone2 varchar(255), webSite varchar(255), primary key (companyId))
    Hibernate: create table Student (StudentId varchar(255) not null, address text, city varchar(255), country varchar(255), dob date, emailId varchar(255) not null, firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), password varchar(255) not null, phone1 varchar(255), phone2 varchar(255), state varchar(255), primary key (StudentId))
    Hibernate: create table User (userId varchar(255) not null, enabled boolean not null, password varchar(255), role varchar(255), primary key (userId))
    Feb 28, 2015 5:44:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
    Feb 28, 2015 5:44:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Feb 28, 2015 5:44:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Feb 28, 2015 5:44:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 19113 ms
    Hibernate: insert into User (enabled, password, role, userId) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
    Feb 28, 2015 5:44:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/JobSearch] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"
      Position: 13
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.saveUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.kharoud.mystore.controller.Admin.AddCompany(Admin.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: if i remove line where i am saving user it results no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a NullPointerException at all. Just read:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"

`user` is a reserved SQL keyword. Don't use it as your table name.

Comment: Yes sir it was sqlException in this console output. I changed the User name to Users and now when i run it results in NullPointerException due to User user = null;  when i change it to User user = new Users(); it saves fine. But i was under impression that using new is bad coding in Spring mvc. Is there any other way around it without using new

Comment: Using new to instantiate a dependency of your controller (like the UserService or CompanyService) that should be injected is indeed bad practice. But `User` is not a dependency of your controller. It's just an entity that you need to create and save when a method is called. It shouldn't be a field of your class, but only a local variable. And obviously, calling a method on a null object will always throw a NullPointerException. What is bad practice though is to disrespect Java naming conventions. Methods start with a lowercase letter in Java.

Comment: Thank you sir. It was helpful. And i started my AddCompany method uppercase by mistake(removed setup from the upper GET method and didn't notice capital A) Hope to avoid these mistakes in future. So it is ok to use new in controller. Thank you sir.